# Jib plugin not able to access project.version as updated by another Gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, plugins, jib

I have my `build.gradle` setup as follows (listing only plugins for brevity)

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'maven-publish'
  id 'signing'
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
  id 'com.limark.gitflowsemver' version '0.3.1'
  id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version '1.8.0'
}
...
group = 'com.app.my'
// The below line remains commented
// version = '0.1.0' 
...

jib {
  from {
    image = 'azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11-jre'
  }
  to {
    image = 'aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/my-app'
    tags = [version]
  }
  container {
    format = 'OCI'
  }
}

publishing {
  repositories {
    maven {
      def releasesRepoUrl = "http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/"
      def snapshotsRepoUrl = "http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/"
      url = version.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? snapshotsRepoUrl : releasesRepoUrl
      credentials {
        username nexusUsername
        password nexusPassword
      }
    }
  }
  publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
      artifactId = 'my-app'
      from components.java
      pom {
        name = 'My App'
        description = 'My App'
        url = 'https://my-app.com'
        developers {
          developer {
            id = 'john'
            name = 'John Doe'
            email = 'an.emaill@address.here'
          }
        }
        scm {
          connection = 'scm:git:ssh://git@bitbucket.org:acme/my-app.git'
          developerConnection = 'scm:git:ssh://git@bitbucket.org:acme/my-app.git'
          url = 'https://bitbucket.org/acme/my-app'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

signing {
  sign publishing.publications.mavenJava
}
```

The `gitflowsemver` [plugin](https://github.com/OpenLimark/GitFlowSemVerPlugin) updates the `project.version` based on the GitFlow branching strategy. The `publish` task is able to access the version as updated by the `gitflowsemver` plugin, but when I try to build a docker image using `jib`, it does not tag the image with the updated version. It is always tagged as `unspecified`. But if I un-comment the line `version = '0.1.0'` the `jib` plugin is able to pick up the version. I am unable to understand why. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: Jib **2.6.0** now has support for late evaluation of `jib.to.image` and `jib.to.tags`. You can configure these using `project.provider` and they will only be evaluated when they are used.

```
jib {
  ...
  to {
    image = 'rishabh9/jib-demo'
    tags = project.provider{[version]}
  }
  ...
}
```

---

For older versions of jib you can try the previous answer:

From the solution discussed on gitter.im/google/jib

Looking into the code of the gitsemver plugin you can see that it updates the version after the project is evaluated: https://github.com/OpenLimark/GitFlowSemVerPlugin/blob/develop/src/main/groovy/com/limark/open/gradle/plugins/gitflowsemver/GitFlowSemVerPlugin.groovy#L51

So what you can do is just set your tag version in an afterEvaluate block and you'll correctly pick up the version:

```
jib {
  ...
  to {
    image = 'rishabh9/jib-demo'
    project.afterEvaluate { // <-- so we evaluate version after it has been set
      tags = [version]
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: where does `version` come? Project version?

Comment: in case someone like me is wondering `version` as expected the project version